# SCSS / SASS Math Error?

Tags: css, sass, less

I'm converting some LESS files to SCSS and it seems to be having issues w/ the math in using in the stylesheet.

```
.class {
    ....
    bottom: #{((52+32)/2)/14em};
    ...
}
```

Is compiling to 3/em and generating an error?
Can SASS not handle complicated Math?

Comment: I think the `em` needs to be outside of the curly braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `em` needs to be outside of the curly braces.

```
.class {
    ....
    bottom: #{((52+32)/2)/14}em;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ah-ha, thank you. This worked width: #{620/840*100%}; which led me to believe it should go inside. It's strange how it wants percentage inside and em outside.